# Is it possible to configure conda python environment using RStudio Server with reticulate on CentOS 7?

Tags: python, r, centos7, conda, reticulate

I am trying to get a bunch of my python using colleagues on board with using RStudio Server. I was under the impression that python users could use the `reticulate` package to manage their conda environments. While optimistically named commands are there in the package, they unfortunately don't actually do what they appear to. It appears from this github issue that RStudio Server with `reticulate` is actually completely useless from the perspective of python users: they cannot manage their conda environments from R.

https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/292

Has anyone found a workaround for allowing a user of an RStudio Server session to modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately just for their session or project? Could a specific conda environment be activated their .Rprofile for instance?

I am using the open source RStudio Server 1.2 preview with:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

I created the following conda environment:

```
$ conda create -n spec35 python=3.5 numpy pandas matplotlib
```

Then I ran the following code in R:

```
library(reticulate)

conda_env = "/home/wdkrnls/.conda/envs/spec35"
use_python(file.path(conda_env, "bin/python"))
use_condaenv(conda_env)
```

I see the following error when I try to evaluate `print(1+1)` in a python block:

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found
```